# Switching Styles

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

Let's say I have multiple styles.xml files (with different names of course) for themes. Is it possible to choose which file the app should pull from?

White style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="mybutton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">45dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#202020</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_btnbg</item>
    </style>

...
```

Black style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="mybutton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">45dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/black_btnbg</item>
    </style>

...
```

So then, in my layout xml all my button's styles would be set to "mybutton" and depending which theme the user chose it would pull from the coordinating file.
Since it isn't possible to change a view's style at runtime is it possible to do this? Or is there a better way (i'm sure there is) to change styles?

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple styles with different names. Then you can set the backGround programmatically:

```
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blabla);
```

Comment: I know that, but that isn't the question.

Comment: You cant change a style on runtime, but you can change the style that the view is using. so you can use multiple styles and you can decide which one to use on runtime programmaticaly.

Comment: Am i miss understanding something? :) You can create different xml files which define the styles of your buttons. put them under drawable folder. when user selects a theme , for instance onClick of a button, change the background of all buttons in your application programmatically.

Comment: No, you understand that correctly.. But to do it that way I have to change the background, text color etc each one by one. I'm wondering if there is an easier way.